# Simple Input Text Analysis

Tags: java, datetime, validation, primes, palindrome

I've started learning java. I've written a small program I've done in C before. It's simple input analysis. If there is

1. number, program checks if number is prime. Then write number: (value of input variable) (prime) for example
2. date in format DD/MM/YYYY, if does program will print date: DD/MM/YYYY Day (Day represents Monday, ...)
3. word (plus everything whats not date or number). There program checks, if input isn't palindrome.

So. I would like to ask you, if the code is good or not (and where it isn't). I would like to improve. I'm new in OOP so there may be some mistakes. As I said, I've been working in C before.

```
package inputtextanalysis;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Johnczek
 */

public class InputTextAnalysis {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input Text Analysis. For help type \"-help\", for exiting program type \"exit\"");
        System.out.print("Type text here: ");

        while(true) 
        {
            Detect.detection(sc.next());   
        }
    }

}


class Detect {
    private static int count=0;
    private String s;

    static void detection(String s) 
    {
        if(null != s)
        switch (s) {
            case "exit":
                printExitMessage();
                System.exit(0x0);
            case "-help":
                printHelp();
                break;
            default:
                if(s.matches("^-?\\d+$"))
                {
                    try {
                        if(isPrime(Long.parseLong(s)))
                            printPrimeNumberInfo(s);
                        else
                            printNumberInfo(s);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("#ERROR# Long overflow/ underflow");
                        System.out.println("Maximum value: " + Long.MAX_VALUE + " | " + "Minimum value " + Long.MIN_VALUE);
                        System.out.println("Try again please");
                        count--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if(isValidDate(s))
                    printDateInfo(s);
                else
                {
                    if(isPalindrome(s))
                        printPalindromeWordInfo(s);
                    else
                        printWordInfo(s);
                }   count++;
                break;
        }   
    }

    public static void printNumberInfo(String s) 
    {
        System.out.println("number: " + s);
    }
    public static void printPrimeNumberInfo(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("number: " + s + " (prime)");
    }
    public static void printDateInfo(String s)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("date: " + s + " (" + getDay(s) + ")");
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Detect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public static void printWordInfo(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("word: " + s);
    }
    public static void printPalindromeWordInfo(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("word: " + s + " (palindrome)");
    }
    public static void printExitMessage()
    {
        System.out.println("Exiting program. " + count + " objects loaded");
        System.out.println("Thanks for using this program");     
    }
    public static void printHelp()
    {
        System.out.println("============================ Input Text Analysis ============================");
        System.out.println("Program loads data from input. Then prints info about these datas on output");
        System.out.println("In case a) input is number, program checks if the number is prime or not");
        System.out.println("In case b) input is in date type (DD/MM/YYYY) program calculate the day");
        System.out.println("In other case program checks if input is palindrome or not");
        System.out.println("Write \"exit\" for exiting program");
        System.out.println("=============================================================================");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("Type text here: ");
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(long number) 
    {
        if (number%2==0 || number=='2' || number=='1')
            return false;
        for(int i=3; i*i<=number;i+=2)
        {
            if(number%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isValidDate(String s)
    {
        return s.matches("(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\\d\\d$)|(^29[\\/]02[\\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)");
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
    {
        for(int i=0, n=s.length()-1; i<n; i++, n--)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(n))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String getDay(String s) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dt1=format1.parse(s);
        DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
        String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
        return finalDay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `try`-with-resources

> ```
>         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>         System.out.println("Input Text Analysis. For help type \"-help\", for exiting program type \"exit\"");
>         System.out.print("Type text here: ");
>
>         while(true) 
>         {
>             Detect.detection(sc.next());   
>         }
> ```

My IDE will complain that you never close the `Scanner`.  If you put the whole thing in a `try`-with-resources block, it stops complaining.

```
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Input Text Analysis. For help type \"-help\", for exiting program type \"exit\"");
            System.out.print("Type text here: ");

            while (true) {
                Detect.detection(sc.next());
            }
        }
```

This is a good pattern to learn.  It doesn't matter much with a `Scanner` that you declare in `main` (whatever my IDE says), but in other circumstances, leaving an unclosed resource can cause memory leaks or other issues.

Note that this is a normal `try` block otherwise.  It could catch an exception or add a `finally` block.  I just didn't need to do so here.  The [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) will handle the declared object and close it cleanly if it is open.

In Java, the general standard is to put the `{` on the same line as its control statement, not alone on its own line.  So long as you are consistent in your codebase, it's not a huge deal to do it the other way.  But since you aren't consistent here, I'm doing it the "standard" way.

#### Prefer early exit for exceptional conditions

> ```
>         if(null != s)
> ```

The entire method is inside this `if`.  First, I think that this is exactly the situation where using the single statement form of `if` is dangerous.  It would be easy to forget that everything else is inside the `switch` statement and add a new statement after the switch.

Second, this is easily avoidable.

```
        if (null == s) {
            return;
        }
```

Now it doesn't matter what statements we may add outside the scope of the `if`.  If `s` is null, we panic immediately.  It might be better to throw an exception here, but I'll leave that up to you.

#### Don't assume

> ```
>                     catch (Exception e) {
>                         System.out.println("#ERROR# Long overflow/ underflow");
> ```

You catch a generic exception and then assume that it is a `Long` overflow or underflow.  It would be better to catch a more specific exception (or exceptions) and handle those.  Otherwise, you may find that your response makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In term of OOP I would say that I don't see any OOP principle.

Why not creating a `Number` class with one `static accept(String str):boolean` and the `printXxxxInfo` methods in it. And the same for `Date` and `Sentence`.
This way, the internals of all classes are grouped in themselves.

```
default:
  if ( Number.accept(s) ) {
    new Number(s).printInfo(); // If (this.isPrime()) { .. } else { .. }
  } else if ( Date.accept(s) ) {
    new Date(s).printInfo();
  } else {
    new Sentence(s).printInfo();
  }
```

Much better, you can create an abstract class for your inputs and use it as parent for `Number`,  `Date` and `Sentence` and use a *factory* to create them :

```
default:
  Input input = Inputs.parse(s); // Factory method for inputs
  input.printInfo();
```

Also, I prefer to remove the `System.out` from my classes. This is cleaner and easier to test. So instead of printing the infos to `System.out` from your inputs, you can ask them the info and print it.

```
default:
  Input input = Inputs.parse(s);
  System.out.println(input.getInfo());
```